# Math explanation of why this code works

Tags: javascript, math

I encountered a problem in the site CodeFights that I resolved with two loops. While looking at other answer I found one that resolved it with no loops and it left me with my mouth open. The coder applied Math.min/max , and while I do understand what the code does I don't understand why it works.

I've love to learn because heck, Math.max/min beats the bytes out of my loops for sure.

```
Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum
of two integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r.

Example

For n = 6, l = 2 and r = 4, the output should be
countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) = 2.

There are just two ways to write 6 as A + B, where 2 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 4: 6 = 2 + 4 and 6 = 3 + 3.

Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (js)
[input] integer n

A positive integer.

Constraints:
5 ≤ n ≤ 109.

[input] integer l

A positive integer.

Constraints:
1 ≤ l ≤ r.

[input] integer r

A positive integer.

Constraints:
l ≤ r ≤ 109,
r - l ≤ 106.
```

The coder's amazing answer:

```
function countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) {
    return Math.max(Math.min(Math.floor(n / 2) - l, r - Math.ceil(n / 2)) + 1, 0);
}
```

My crap in comparison:

```
function countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) {
    var representations = 0;
    //Only travel the loop until n/2 , because l+r will never equal n
    // if l or r > n/2
    var limit = Math.floor(n/2);
    for(var i=l; i<=r && i<=limit; ++i){
        for(var j=i;j<=r;++j){ 
            if(i+j == n){
                ++representations;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    return representations;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given integers `n`, `l` and `r`, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers `A` and `B` such that `l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r`.

First, consider that if `n` is even and letting `x = n/2`, we have at least one solution (`x + x`) if, and only if, `l ≤ x ≤ r`. If `x` isn't in that range then there is no solution, since either `x < l` and `l + l > n` or `r < x` and `r + r < n`.

That can be generalized to even or odd `n`: There is a solution if, and only, if: `l ≤ floor(x) ≤ ceil(x) ≤ r`. If we let `A = floor(x)` and `B = ceil(x)`, that solution is `A + B`. Every other solution can be found by taking one step along the number line away from that point in each direction. `(A - 1) + (B + 1) = A + B = n`, therefore `(A - 1) + (B + 1)` is a solution as long as `(A - 1)` hasn't crossed the `l` boundary and `(B + 1)` hasn't crossed the `r` boundary. So, if you wanted a solution with only one loop, you could do something like this:

```
function countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) {
    var x = n/2;
    var A = Math.floor( x );
    var B = Math.ceil( x );
    for ( var count = 0; l <= A && B <= r; count++) {
        A--;
        B++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

But how many times does that loop iterate? Well, it iterates until one of the stopping conditions happens:

1. `A` becomes smaller than `l`
2. `B` becomes larger than `r`

If `1.` happens first, then it iterates `Math.floor( x ) - l + 1` times, whereas if `2.` happens first it iterates `r - Math.ceil( x ) + 1` (if both conditions happen on the same iteration, then `Math.floor( x ) - l === r - Math.ceil( x )`).

As long as there is a solution the loop iterates the smaller of `Math.floor( x ) - l + 1` or `r - Math.ceil( x ) + 1` times, which is where the coder got the answer `Math.min(Math.floor(n / 2) - l, r - Math.ceil(n / 2)) + 1` from (after substituting `x` back for `n/2` and pulling the `+ 1` out of each term and adding it after instead.

If there is no solution, `EG. n = 10, l = 20, r = 20`, that formula will give a negative result, but it should give `0` instead, which is why he added `Math.max( result, 0 );`.

For clarity, the coder's solution could be written as (still with no loops):

```
function countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) {
    var x = n/2;
    var A = Math.floor( x );
    var B = Math.ceil( x );

    // Every solution is of the form (A - i) + (B + i), where i is an integer >= 0

    // How many values of i are valid for l <= (A - i)
    var stepsA = A - l + 1;

    // How many values of i are valid for (B + i) <= r
    var stepsB = r - B + 1;

    // If the formulas gave a negative amount of valid steps, 
    // there is no solution, so return 0
    if ( stepsA < 0 || stepsB < 0 )
        return 0;

    // Otherwise, return the smaller valid amount of steps,
    // that is the number of steps that are valid for both A and B
    return Math.min(stepsA, stepsB);
}
```